# Remove date from filter context

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have written the following measure that will give new employer names. I have put a date slicer(Dates table is connected to `LearningPlan[StartDate]`) on the visual but I want this measure to ignore any date in the slicer. I have included an image of data set for reference.

```
    New Employer = 
    VAR Current_Employer = (CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE(LearningPlan,LearningPlan[Employer name]), DATESBETWEEN(LearningPlan[Start Date], MIN(LearningPlan[Start Date]), EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1))))

    RETURN
    COUNTROWS(CALCULATETABLE(FILTER(SUMMARIZE(LearningPlan,LearningPlan[Employer name]),NOT LearningPlan[Employer name] IN Current_Employer)))
```

sample data:

[image: sample data]

I have tried putting ALL at the end of "New_Employer" like below but it doesn't do anything. The reason I want to do this is if I have a visualisation on the same page I don't want the new employer visual to be affected.

```
    New Employer = 
    VAR Current_Employer = (CALCULATETABLE(SUMMARIZE(LearningPlan,LearningPlan[Employer name]), DATESBETWEEN(LearningPlan[Start Date], MIN(LearningPlan[Start Date]), EOMONTH(TODAY(), -1)),ALL('Date'))
```

filtering by these should not include JD sports as they are not a new employer:

[image: img2]

Comment: Looks like i solved it.
I did CALCULATE(New Employer. ALL('Date')